# Specular power of zero in pixel shader removes ambient and diffuse

Tags: directx, direct3d, hlsl, lighting

I've added a specular component to my basic light shader and I'm having some problem with specular power. If I set it's value to 0, instead of an expected matte object without specular highlights, I'm getting a weird effect where only directly lit surface is visible, while ambient and diffuse components are ignored.

The image below illustrates this problem:

[image: Globe screenshots]

I can still get rid of the specular element by setting `specularIntensity` to 0, but I assumed setting `specularPower` to 0 would have the same effect.  Below is my pixel shader code and I can't figure out what's wrong with it:

```
float4 LightPixelShader(PixelInputType input) : SV_Target
{   
    float4 specular;

    // Sample the pixel color from the texture using the sampler at this texture coordinate location.
    float4 textureColor = shaderTexture.Sample(SampleType, input.tex);

    // Set default output color to ambient light value for all pixels
    float4 color = ambientColor;

    // Invert the light direction for calculations.
    float3 lightDir = -lightDirection;

    // Calculate the amount of light on this pixel.
    float lightIntensity = saturate(dot(input.normal, lightDir));

    if (lightIntensity > 0.0f)
    {
        // Determine final diffuse color
        color += (diffuseColor * lightIntensity);

        // Saturate ambient and diffuse color
        color = saturate(color);

        // Calculate the reflection vector based on the light intensity, normal vector and light direction
        float3 reflection = normalize(2 * dot(lightDir, input.normal) * input.normal     - lightDir);

        // Determine the amount of specular light based on the reflection vector, viewing direction and specular power
        specular = specularIntensity * specularColor * pow(saturate(dot(reflection, normalize(input.viewDirection))), specularPower);
    }

    // Saturate the final color in case it's greater then 1
    color = saturate(color);

    // Multiply the texture pixel and the final diffuse color to get the final pixel color result.
    color = color * textureColor;

    // Add the specular component
    color = saturate(color + specular);

    return color;
 }
```

Comment: Initialize `specular` to `float4(0, 0, 0, 0)` so you don't change the color if the pixel is unlit. That's probably why even the ambient component is gone.

Comment: It doesn't seem to change much.

Comment: What does "not much" mean? Does the ambient component reappear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is this innocent-looking line here:

```
specular = specularIntensity * specularColor * pow(saturate(dot(reflection, normalize(input.viewDirection))), specularPower);
```

When `specularPower` is zero, `specular` always winds up as one because any variable raised to the zero power is 1.  So that last globe you're seeing is a view of the specular reflection of all pixels with specular reflection.

But your question asked for help finding a problem in the code.  I didn't offer one because, strictly speaking, there isn't one - because there is no problem.  It's just a quirk of specularity.

Comment: But, with a proper implementation, shouldn't specular power (also known as shininess) of 0 result in a perfectly matte object? If the formula is right, does adding a `if (specularPower <= 0) specular = 0;` statement make sense?

Comment: @Marian No, it wouldn't.  "Shininess" in the shader above is less about matte vs. shininess. Rather, it's the degree to which a point light source can be perturbed by scattering and reflect back to the camera.  A very high shininess value means the surface is very smooth, so only a few concentrated pixels reflect light back to the camera.  With a shininess (smoothenss) of zero, the surface is completely rough, modeling a material where light bouncing off a surface reflects uniformly in all directions (i.e. the bottom-right image).

Comment: Ran out of characters... Indeed, if you vary the shininess value continuously from 1 to 0, you'll see the image change slowly from the bottom-left image to the bottom-right image.  The value 0 is not a discontinuity.

Comment: @Marian No, it really doesn't make sense.  The primary objective of a pixel shader is to be fast.  Even on a small 1024 x 768 window, assuming a low overdraw of 200%, the pixel shader is called 1,572,864 times _every frame_ - and this number increases exponentially with the size of the window.  So, adding any unnecessary code to a pixel shader is generally a bad idea.  If, for whatever reason, you _really_ want to add such a functionality, you'd do it over on the C++ side (checking only once per frame), not in HLSL.

Answer (score 1):

The shader below can trigger undefined behavior. when you end to a computation of pow(0,0) it could result to 0 or NAN according to the documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509636%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This is because pow(x,y) is implement as exp( y * ln( x ) ).

Once you have a NAN everything is possible on screen, but it often ends as black and this is why a large part of the sphere disappear.